# Phonegap/Cordova jQuery Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing, cordova

I'm developing a Cordova App, I have a variable call `one` which contains following:

```
Lorem Iépsum "Dolor sit", 2do. Blah, House Nº 31.<br>Monday / Friday, de 2:00 pm. a 6:00 pm.<br>Teléfono: <a href="tel:555777"555-777</a> Ext. 032.<br>
```

If I do:

```
two=$(one).text();
```

I got the error:

```
file:///android_asset/www/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js: Line 2 : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Lorem Iépsum "Dolor sit", 2do. Blah, House Nº 31.<br>Monday / Friday, de 2:00 pm. a 6:00 pm.<br>Teléfono: <a href="tel:555777"555-777</a> Ext. 032.<br>
```

Why is this happening?
Is it because it contains characters with accents and tildes?
Or is for the reason that contains quotes?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a text like `Lorem Iépsum "Dolor sit", 2do. Blah, House Nº 31.<br>Monday / Friday, de 2:00 pm. a 6:00 pm.<br>Teléfono: <a href="tel:555777"555-777</a> Ext. 032.<br>` jQuery considers it to be a selector, so it fails the selector validation because if the `<` and `>` characters.

If you want to construct a html element using the string then you need to wrap the string using a html element like

```
var two = $('<div />', {
    html: one
})
```

It creates a `div` element with the string of `one` as its content.

If you want [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) to consider the passed string as a html string to construct a new element then in has to start with `<`

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4xTt9/1/), [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4xTt9/2/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I really want is to remove the HTML code, I just want the text and save it to a variable. How I can do the parsing?

Comment: you want to remove the html elements and its contents or just the elements but have to retain its contents

Comment: The output should be: Lorem Iépsum "Dolor sit", 2do. Blah, House Nº 31.
Monday / Friday, de 2:00 pm. a 6:00 pm.
Teléfono: 555-777 Ext. 032.

Comment: @candlejack in that case `var two = $('<div />', {
    html: one
}).text();` as given in the [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4xTt9/3/)

Comment: Fine, but missing this "555-777"

Comment: @candlejack because your string is not proper, the `a` tag is not closed `Lorem Iépsum "Dolor sit", 2do. Blah, House Nº 31.<br>Monday / Friday, de 2:00 pm. a 6:00 pm.<br>Teléfono: <a href="tel:555777">555-777</a> Ext. 032.<br>` - missing `>` in `href="tel:555777">`

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been right from the beginning.